# Can I manipulate symbols like I manipulate strings?

Tags: julia

**Question:** Can I divide a symbol into two symbols based on a letter or symbol?

**Example:** For example, let's say I have `:symbol1_symbol2`, and I want to split it on the `_` into `:symbol1` and `:symbol2`. Is this possible?

**Motivation:** A fairly common recommendation in Julia is to use `Symbol` in place of `String` or `ASCIIString` as it is more efficient for many operations. So I'm interested in situations where this might break down because there is no analogue for `Symbol` for an operation that we might typically perform on `ASCIIString`, e.g. anything to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't manipulate symbols.
They are not a composite type (in logic, though they maybe in implement).
They are one thing.
Much like an integer is one thing,
or a boolean is one thing.
You can't manipulate the parts of it.

As I understand, it the reason they are fast is because thay are "one thing".

Symbols are not strings.
Symbols are the representation of a parsed token.
They exist for working with macros etc.

They are useful for other things.
Though one fo there most common alterate uses in 0.3 was as a standin for enumerations. Now that Enum is in 0.4, that use will decline.
They are still logically good for dictionary keys etc.

--

If for some reason you must.
Eg for interop with a 3rd party library, or for some kind of dynamic dispatch:

You can convert it to a String,
with `string(:abc)`, (There is not currently a `convert`),
and back with `Symbol("abc")`.

so

```
function symsplit(s_s::Symbol)
    combined_string_from=string(s_s)
    strings= split(combined_string_from, '_')
    map(Symbol,strings)
end


@show  symsplit(:a)
@show  symsplit(:a_b)
@show symsplit(:a_b_c);
```

but please don't.

You can find all the methods that operate on symbols by calling `methodswith(Symbol)` (though most just use the symbol as a marker/enum)

---

See also:

[What is a "symbol" in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480722/what-is-a-symbol-in-julia)

Comment: That all makes sense to me. Thanks for responding.