# Julia DataFrame columns starting with number?

Tags: julia

This may be a stupid question, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get Julia to read a csv file with column names that start with numbers and use them in DataFrames.  How does one do this?

For example, say I have the file "test.csv" which contains the following:

```
,1Y,2Y,3Y
1Y,11,12,13
2Y,21,22,23
```

If I just use readtable(), I get this:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = readtable("test.csv")
2x4 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | x    | x1Y | x2Y | x3Y |
|-----|------|-----|-----|-----|
| 1   | "1Y" | 11  | 12  | 13  |
| 2   | "2Y" | 21  | 22  | 23  |
```

What gives?  How can I get the column names to be what they're supposed to be, "1Y, "2Y, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in DataFrames, column names are [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480722/what-is-a-symbol-in-julia), which aren't meant to (see comment below) start with a number.

You can see this by doing e.g. `typeof(:2)`, which will return `Int64`, rather than (as you might expect) `Symbol`. Thus, to get your columnnames into a useable format, DataFrames will have to prefix it with a letter - `typeof(:x2)` will return `Symbol`, and is therefore a valid column name.

Comment: Strictly speaking, symbols can start with a number, e.g., `Symbol("1Y")`, but they become very unwieldy.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't use numbers for starting names in DataFrames.

The [code that does the parsing of names](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl/blob/master/src/other/utils.jl#L20) makes sure that this restriction stays like this.

I believe this is because of how parsing takes place in julia: `:aa` names a symbol, while `:2aa` is a value (makes more sense considering `1:2aa` is a range)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `rename!()` after the import:

```
df = csv"""
,1Y,2Y,3Y
1Y,11,12,13
2Y,21,22,23
"""
rename!(df, Dict(:x1Y =>Symbol("1Y"), :x2Y=>Symbol("2Y"), :x3Y=>Symbol("3Y")  ))

2×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x    │ 1Y │ 2Y │ 3Y │
├─────┼──────┼────┼────┼────┤
│ 1   │ "1Y" │ 11 │ 12 │ 13 │
│ 2   │ "2Y" │ 21 │ 22 │ 23 │
```

Still you may experience problems later in your code, better to avoid column names starting with numbers...

Comment: The point is sort of that the input files had these column names.