# How to remove multiple columns by name in a julia dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, julia

In the [wikibook documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/DataFrames#Adding.2C_deleting.2C_and_renaming_columns) it is said that `delete!` can be applied to a set of columns, but I am not able to get it, in order to delete several columns by name in a single passage.

I did tried also using list comprehension, but I still got an error (while for multiple dataframes only it works):

```
[delete!(df, :colname) for df in [df1, df2, df3], colname in ["col2","col5"]];
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, dataframes uses a symbol (`:foo`) instead of a string (`"foo"`) to index a column. The explanation of why it is that way is given by one of the creators of the language here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23482257/4746618

Comment: Very interesting discussion. It vaguely resembles me the C pointers and C `*` operator.. Thank you to pointing me to that.

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems that writing on SO gave me the inspiration:

```
[delete!(df, colname) for df in [df1, df2, df3], colname in [:col2,:col5]];
```

or

```
[delete!(df,[:col2,:col5]) for df in [df1, df2, df3]];
```

(I still have to understand what this strange `:` symbol means in Julia, my fault.. ;-) )

Comment: When used in front of a letter, it denotes that that item is a symbol. Packages like DataFrames use symbols to denote column names rather than strings (aka "a"). If used in a situation like `a[1,:]` the `:` represents the concept of all, so this would return every column in the first row.