# Symbols and its equivalent in Python

Tags: python, julia

I want to know the equivalent of the julia type "symbols" in Python because i am trying to translate a code that i am working on, from julia to Python.
Thank you

Comment: To answer the question, we need to know whether you are using `Symbol` types because they are [interned strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) or whether you are using them for their ability to represent Julia code itself, e.g. in conjunction with the `Expr` type, meta-programming, `@eval` e.t.c. If you're not sure, then it is *very* likely you are just using them as interned strings in which case the answer provided by @thebjorn is perfectly satisfactory (or if speed doesn't matter you can just replace them with strings, as @NedBatchelder suggests).

Answer (score 0):

The `intern(s)` function may do what you want:

```
>>> help(intern)
Help on built-in function intern in module __builtin__:

intern(...)
    intern(string) -> string

    ``Intern'' the given string.  This enters the string in the (global)
    table of interned strings whose purpose is to speed up dictionary lookups.
    Return the string itself or the previously interned string object with the
    same value.

>>>
```

Comment: what aboiut if i used only strings instead of symbols, i think it's convinient too.

Comment: See Colin's comment on your question for reasons to chose one over the other. Strings are definitely convenient (`intern` returns a string, but such that `intern('hello' + ' ' + 'world') is intern('hello world')` -- notice the `is` which is faster than `==`).  If you don't care about that kind of performance, but need more functionality then creating a subclass of `str` might be a solution. It really all depends on what you're going to use them for...

Comment: BTW, in Python 3, intern seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @NedBatchelder how so?  (`"hello " + "world" is "hello world"` returns False, while wrapping in `sys.intern(..)` returns True).

Comment: Ah, this gets subtle, as undocumented implementation details often do. If the string is a valid identifier, then it's interned:  `"he"+"llo" is "hell"+"o"` --> True.  Better not to depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use strings instead.  What do symbols do that strings don't do?

Comment: Regarding what symbols do, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480722/what-is-a-symbol-in-julia.

Comment: That post seems to indicate that symbols are important for representing the program as data, which I suspect most actual programs are not doing.  We'll need to hear from the OP about what symbols are being used for in their program.

Comment: actually that makes sense

Comment: i'm still quit new on Julia for example one of the things that i didn't understand about one of Symbols commads is this one: `aH = symbols(printf("a_H1:%d", n+1))`

Comment: It will be hard to help one line at a time.  We'd need to see what `aH` is used for.

Comment: okay here is a part of the  julia code that i am trying to translate to Python :    `mutable struct QRelaySym{T<:Tuple}
    aH::T
    bH::T
    aV::T
    bV::T
    apH::T
    bpH::T
    apV::T
    bpV::T
end `