# What is difference between Symbol and Sym in dataframe Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I was wondering what the difference is between the `Symbol` type and `Sym` type in dataframe in Julia. Here is an example with `Symbol` which is defined with `:`:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(V1 = [:True, :False])
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ V1     
     │ Symbol 
─────┼────────
   1 │ True
   2 │ False
```

As you can see the type is now a Symbol. If we define it just like True/False the type will be Sym like this:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(V1 = [True, False])
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ V1    
     │ Sym   
─────┼───────
   1 │  True
   2 │ False
```

As you can see the type is now `Sym`. Here using `typeof` for both True:

```
julia> typeof(:True)
Symbol

julia> typeof(True)
Sym
```

I know we have this beautiful answer: [What is a "symbol" in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480722/what-is-a-symbol-in-julia), but I can't find anything about `Sym`. So I was wondering what is the difference between `Symbol` and `Sym` in a dataframe of `Julia`?

---

Version of `DataFrames`:

```
julia> Pkg.status("DataFrames")
Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.8/Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v1.4.4
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. `DataFrame(V1 = [True, False]); ERROR: UndefVarError: True not defined`. Maybe you load/autoload packages that define `Sym`?

Comment: Potentially `Symbolics.jl` is in your `startup.jl`?

Comment: Hi @AndreWildberg, You were right, the problem was the `SymPy` package. But is it still not weird that the name of the type changes?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature :) The added functionality interfered with expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When removing the `SymPy` package with `Pkg.rm("SymPy")`, the `sym` type is gone:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(V1 = [True, False])
ERROR: UndefVarError: True not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

Comment: `Sym` is a type defined in `SymPy` and the type of `True` and `False`.  Whereas `:True` and `:False` are using `Julia's` notation to create a symbol (the colon). Symbols have type `Symbol`. In each case, `DataFrames` just prints the type of the vector for the column.