# Is `exec` the Python counterpart to Scheme's `apply`?

Tags: python, scheme

I found the Python built-in function `eval`, but failed to find a function that is analogous to Scheme's `apply`.

I have exhaustively examined other Python keywords, but none of them match `apply`.

A candidate might be `exec`:

```
In [14]: eval("print('testing')")      
testing
In [15]: exec("print('testing')")      
testing
```

and in Scheme:

```
> (eval '(display 'testing))
testing
> (apply display '(testing))
testing
```

Is Python's `exec` the counterpart to Scheme's `apply`?

Comment: define `apply`?

Comment: implement to apply procedure to arguments. @Chris_Rands

Comment: In Python that would be `print(*args)`…!?

Comment: emmm, crazy imagination with little sense. @deceze

Comment: Are you looking for `map()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Scheme's `apply` is used to apply a function to arguments stored in a list. The Python way to do that is `*`, not `exec`:

```
>>> args = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(*args)
1 2 3
```

Python [used to](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply) have an `apply` function matching Scheme's `apply`, but it was removed in favor of `*` notation.

Answer (score 2):

To define apply in Python:

```
def apply(f, arg_list):
    return f(*arg_list)
```

Scheme example:

```
(define (pythagoras a b)
  (sqrt (+ (* a a) (* b b))))

(apply pythagoras '(3 4))  ; Returns: 5
```

Analogous Python example:

```
import math

def pythagoras(a, b):
    return math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2)

apply(pythagoras, [3, 4])  # Returns: 5.0
```

**Side notes** (based on your apparent interest in such things)

Python's `eval`:

```
eval('pythagoras(3, 4)')
```

Whereas in Scheme:

```
(eval '(pythagoras 3 4))
(eval "Hello")
(eval `(,(if (> x 0) + -) 100 ,(pythagoras 3 4)))
```

As you can see, Python's `eval` requires you to fiddle with strings, bytes or "code objects". Scheme's `eval` takes in Scheme. See: [What exactly does homoiconicity mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492704/what-exactly-does-homoiconicity-mean)

You may be interested in reading about [The Metacircular Evaluator](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html) (from *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs*, chapter 4, Metalinguistic Abstractions) to see the meaning of Scheme's `eval` and `apply`.

Note that the use of `eval` in Python is heavily discouraged (and if you really need to use it, consider [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead). In both languages, you are generally advised to avoid `eval` if your problem can be solved using other methods.